# Slow Build of .NET Solution for Azure Functions using Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

We are using Azure Pipelines to deploy a .NET Azure Function App. In Visual Studio, restoring and building the solution is a matter of seconds. Using the pipeline, **the `dotnet restore` step takes around 3 minutes**. It is not a large solution, and so we are wondering whether we did something wrong. We also tried running the pipeline on both hosted and self-hosted pipelines, but the issue remained the same.

Our Pipeline template to build the solution looks as follows:

```
parameters:
  - name: is_debug_active
    type: boolean
    default: false
  - name: project_file_path
    type: string
  - name: build_configuration
    type: string

stages:
  - stage: Build
    jobs:
      - job:
        pool:
          vmImage: "windows-latest"

        steps:
          - ${{ each parameter in parameters }}:
              - script: |
                  echo ${{parameter.Key}} : ${{parameter.Value}}
                condition: eq(${{parameters.is_debug_active}}, True)

          - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
            displayName: Building and publishing...
            inputs:
              command: "publish"
              projects: "${{parameters.project_file_path}}"
              arguments: "--configuration ${{parameters.build_configuration}} --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)"
              publishWebProjects: false
              zipAfterPublish: true

          - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
            inputs:
              targetPath: "$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)"
              artifactName: "drop"
              artifactType: "pipeline"
```

**What we tried:** We included a caching step and created lockfiles for all packages, but although a cache hit is reached, the downloaded filesize seems to be smaller than 0.1 MB, and `dotnet restore` takes exactly as much time as before

```
 Resolving key:
     - nuget                          [string]
     - "Windows_NT"                   [string]
     - D:\a\1\s/**/packages.lock.json [file pattern; matches: 8]
       - s\PlatformManagement\Common.Tests\packages.lock.json                   --> 24C75D4A7CE004D32A55DFB8524922037B6F0468CA07BA6A1BA36AFA34FEA148
       - s\PlatformManagement\Common\packages.lock.json                         --> 8661BE7A1A52B3C41DC51A253E4E5A9B09C7C43BCCAFE2AA3C1E1D645CB295B8
       - s\PlatformManagement\DataProductResourceAccess\packages.lock.json      --> 379601DA0A5A838FD75E8D7E1DA6F92DE1CC3364818E61CF2544C215B8E218D7
       - s\PlatformManagement\DataproductManager.Tests\packages.lock.json       --> 115A8DD11A511A9EA9D2D58DCA880C1148508982AA98C9819B727D1085C0DCD3
       - s\PlatformManagement\DataproductManager\packages.lock.json             --> D1666A37C7B64983CE7B57183C9321BFA4F86202089A98625723EC5022DF8363
       - s\PlatformManagement\DataproductResourceAccess.Tests\packages.lock.... --> B40760D9370D92F609E19BC535146E14EB13EE5B594919D73BAD494966D8AEDB
       - s\PlatformManagement\E2E.Tests\packages.lock.json                      --> 1220913195173A205986CB5B9B1FF3B26173EA9AF22D52BAD685051CB7908AB8
       - s\PlatformManagement\Model\packages.lock.json                          --> FC75C9A93232A6B2FE764FDB977E05E4CE4590D1AED20E0419FDA90C583765EA
    Resolved to: nuget|"Windows_NT"|a9beIW4SiPy8P2wvwJbWCtZcLzwh6gLfAwvA4gKB3Cc=
    Resolving restore key:
     - nuget        [string]
     - "Windows_NT" [string]
    Resolved to: nuget|"Windows_NT"|**
    Resolving restore key:
     - nuget [string]
    Resolved to: nuget|**
    Using default max parallelism.
    Max dedup parallelism: 192
    ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender will correlate events with X-TFS-Session da92b437-722a-41ad-9c0c-64da8c42e7df
    Getting a pipeline cache artifact with one of the following fingerprints:
    Fingerprint: `nuget|"Windows_NT"|a9beIW4SiPy8P2wvwJbWCtZcLzwh6gLfAwvA4gKB3Cc=`
    Fingerprint: `nuget|"Windows_NT"|**`
    Fingerprint: `nuget|**`
    There is a cache hit: `nuget|"Windows_NT"|a9beIW4SiPy8P2wvwJbWCtZcLzwh6gLfAwvA4gKB3Cc=`
    Used scope: 138;69cf4639-64d4-439c-addf-77ed81a702dc;refs/heads/feature/6067/nuget-cache;c8fa9810-392f-4de3-8065-34ee5aac671e
    Entry found at fingerprint: `nuget|"Windows_NT"|a9beIW4SiPy8P2wvwJbWCtZcLzwh6gLfAwvA4gKB3Cc=`

    7-Zip 22.01 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2022 Igor Pavlov : 2022-07-15


    Extracting archive: 
    Expected size to be downloaded: 0.0 MB
    Downloaded 0.0 MB out of 0.0 MB (214%).
    Downloaded 0.0 MB out of 0.0 MB (214%).

    Download statistics:
    Total Content: 0.0 MB
    Physical Content Downloaded: 0.0 MB
    Compression Saved: 0.0 MB
    Local Caching Saved: 0.0 MB
    Chunks Downloaded: 3
    Nodes Downloaded: 0
```

Comment: Visual Studio use Ms build command to run the build and publish. So could you directly download the dotNetCore Cli exe in local machine and run the dotnet publish build to see whether it also takes long time to run? Or you could use[ Ms build Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/msbuild?view=azure-devops) in Azure DevOps Pipelines to run the publish command. The working process of the two commands differs(Ms build may restore the needed dependencies for the run, but DotNetCli may work by restoring all the packages or dependencies first). Thanks.

Comment: I tried using `dotnet publish` on my local Visual Studio, and it finished within seconds. In the FAQ of the MSBuild task, it is recommended that the Visual Studio Build task should rather be used.

Comment: Do you install corresponding version [.Net SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=net70#install-with-visual-studio) for running the dotnet publish command? What's things going if you use the [vs build task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/vsbuild-v1?view=azure-pipelines) in ADO pipeline?